# index of smooth varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

What are the simplest examples of smooth, projective varieties defined over the fraction field of an Henselian DVR of characteristic $0$ which have index $>1$?

**EDIT**: Also assume that the residue field of the DVR is algebraically closed.

Comment: What do you mean by index here?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Index is the gcd of the set of degrees of zero dimensional cycles on the variety

Comment: Conics without rational points are usually the easiest examples. For example, the conic over $\mathbb C((a,b))$ given by $\{ax^2 + by^2 = z^2\} \subseteq \mathbb P^2_{\mathbb C((a,b))}$ should be an example.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn What is the index in this case? Could you please elaborate a little on the computation or cite a reference. I also wanted to mention that absence of rational point does not imply index greater than $1$.

Comment: Note that the trace on $C$ of a rational line is a divisor of degree 2. Since $C$ has no degree 1 divisor, its index is exactly 2.

Comment: @abx: Could you please tell if the Brauer group of the field $\mathbb{C}((a,b))$ trivial?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you asked about a Henselian *DVR* (my local ring had higher dimension). This disqualifies my answer (now deleted). The Brauer group of a Henselian DVR with algebraically closed residue field is trivial, so my strategy doesn't work. There might have been an answer of this type to your question before the edit.

Comment: Note that now complete DVRs are also out: they satisfy a higher-dimensional Hensel's lemma for smooth varieties, hence always have a rational point if the residue field is algebraically closed. You would need to find a Henselian DVR that does not satisfy this higher-dimensional Hensel's lemma (which I think should be possible).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn.  "Note that now complete DVRs are also out"  I do not understand this comment.  If the OP were asking for a smooth, projective scheme over $R$ whose generic fiber has index $>1$, then I would completely agree.  However, the OP only asks that the generic fiber is smooth, not that the entire $R$-scheme is $R$-smooth.

Comment: @JasonStarr: ah, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d\geq 3$ be any integer that is relatively prime to the residue characteristic of $R$.  Let $s$ be any generator of the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$.  Let $\widetilde{R}$ be the finite, flat extension $R[\sigma]/\langle \sigma^d -s \rangle$ with its natural action of the group scheme $\mu_d=\text{Spec} \ \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]/\langle \zeta^d-1\rangle$, $$\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]\langle \zeta^d-1 \rangle \times \text{Spec}\ R[\sigma]/\langle \sigma^d-s\rangle \to \text{Spec}\ R[\sigma]/\langle \sigma^d - s\rangle, \ \ \sigma \mapsto \zeta\otimes \sigma.$$  Denote the induced morphism of schemes by $$q:\text{Spec}\ \widetilde{R} \to \text{Spec}\ R.$$  The generic fiber of $q$ is a $\mu_d$-torsor.

Let $X_R$ be the smooth, projective $R$-scheme, $$X_R = \text{Proj}\ R[t_0,t_1,\dots,t_{d-1}]/\langle t_0^d + t_1^d + \dots + t_{d-1}^d \rangle.$$  This has a natural action of $\mu_d$ by $$\zeta\bullet [t_0,t_1,\dots,t_{d-1}] = [\zeta^0t_0,\zeta^1 t_1, \dots, \zeta^{d-1}t_{d-1}].$$  Denote by $X_{\widetilde{R}}$ the base change, $$X_{\widetilde{R}} = \text{Spec}\ \widetilde{R} \times_{\text{Spec}\ R} X_R.$$ This has a diagonal action of $\mu_d$ that is a free action.  The projection to the first factor is equivariant for this action, $$\text{pr}_1:X_{\widetilde{R}} \to \text{Spec}\ \widetilde{R}.$$  Thus, for the geometric quotient by this free $\mu_d$-action, $$q_X:X_{\widetilde{R}} \to \mathcal{X}_R^s,$$ there is a unique morphism, $$\pi:\widetilde{X}_R\to \text{Spec}\ R,$$ such that $\pi\circ q_X$ equals $q\circ \text{pr}_1$.  Since the base change of $\pi$ by the fppf morphism $q$ equals the smooth morphism $\text{pr}_1$, also the proper morphism $\pi$ is smooth.  Since the geometric generic fiber of $\text{pr}_1$ is a smooth hypersurface of dimension $d-2$, it is integral.  Thus, the geometric generic fiber of $\pi$ is also integral.

If $d$ is a prime, then the index of the generic fiber of $\pi$ equals $d$.  Indeed, every zero-dimensional, reduced, closed subscheme of the generic fiber pulls back to a zero-dimensional, reduced, closed subscheme of the generic fiber of $\text{pr}_1$ that is $\mu_d$-invariant.  Thus, for every irreducible component of this closed subscheme, the closure in $X_{\widetilde{R}}$ is an integral, closed subscheme that is $\mu_d$-invariant and finite over $\text{Spec}\ \widetilde{R}$.  By the valuative criterion of properness for $\text{pr}_1$, the intersection of this closed subscheme with the closed fiber of $\text{pr}_1$ is a closed subscheme that is $\mu_d$-invariant.  Since the action of $\mu_d$ on the closed fiber is **free**, the length is divisible by $d$.  Since this holds for every irreducible component, the total length is divisible by $d$.

Comment: Is it obvious that the generic fiber of $\pi$ is smooth?

Comment: @user43198.  "Is it obvious that the generic fiber of $\pi$ is smooth?"  I do not know what is obvious to you.  However, that follows from the Jacobian criterion, since the Jacobian ideal of the Fermat polynomial equals $\langle d t_0^{d-1},\dots, dt_{d-1}^{d-1} \rangle$.

Comment: One further question. Redoing your arguments for a finite, unramified extension $L$ of $K$ (with residue degree $0$) and $R_L$ the integral closure of $R$ in $L$, we will be able to conclude that the generic fiber of the corresponding $\pi_L:\mathcal{X}_{R_L}^s \to \mbox{Spec}(R_L)$ is also of index $d$. The generic fiber of $\pi_L$ should be the base change to $\mbox{Spec}(L)$ of the generic fiber of $\pi$ (unramified extension will ensure that the uniformizer of $R$ and $R_L$ can be the same). Is this correct?

Comment: @user43198 "Is this correct?"  Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you. One last question. Your construction does not seem to require the residue field is algebraically closed. Is this correct i.e., will your construction also work if the residue field of $R$ is not algebraically closed?

Comment: @user43198  The construction does not require that the residue field of $R$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: To be clear you are saying that the generic fiber of $\pi$ satisfies the property that the base change of the generic fiber to any finite unramified extension of the fraction field of $R$, has index $d$. This is a little counter-intuitive for me since I thought that any projective variety after base change by a finite field extension contains a rational point.

Comment: @user43198 "I thought that any projective variety after base change by a finite field extension contains a rational point."  That is certainly true, but there is no guarantee that the finite field extension is "unramified", i.e., is the fraction field of a finite, \'etale extension of DVRs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the subsequent comments.